# Where did the INN name of fentanyl come from?

Tags: nomenclature, drugs

[Fentanyl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fentanyl) is a potent anilidopiperidine opioid. Where did its INN name come from?

[image: Fentanyl]

<sub>Figure 1: Fentanyl</sub>

I know that the INN name of paracetamol came from its chemical name para-acetylaminophenol (**par-acet-am-ol**). Is there a meaningful origin of the INN name of fentanyl?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess: the name may be based on two of the immediate precursors to the drug, N-Phenethyl-4-piperidone (FENT, from Phen + ethyl?) and aniline (ANYL):

[image]

Definitely not as straight-forward as your para-acetylaminophenol example.